# Как по нажатию кнопки на форме что-то сделать на JS и потом запустить сервлет?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlet

Здравствуйте.

Возникла необходимость по нажатию кнопки на форме что-то сделать на JS и потом запустить сервлет.

Каким образом это возможно сделать?

p.s.

попробовал

```js
document.location.href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/NewServlet";
```

Но возникает ошибка 405

```
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
type Status report
message HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

Ошибку с отсутствием обработчика GET в NewServlet я осознал.

Сразу же возник другой вопрос каким образом метод GET поменять на POST в JS, если это конечно возможно?

Comment: 1. Перехватываем стандартное событие нажатия на кнопку.
2. Прекращаем распространение события, сразу, как перехватили его.
3. Делаем, что нам надо.
4. Либо через AJAX либо как-то иначе вызываем сервлет.

Comment: Если на голом JS нет желания писать - можно подключить jQuery. Там с AJAXом всё здорово. И с DOM можно удобно работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаете что-то в JS, вызываете

```
document.forms['form-name'].submit();
```

В форме будет так

```
<form method="POST" action="/folder/some-url.htm" >
```